# Stronglifts 5x5 while on a caloric deficit?

Tags: weight-loss, stronglifts, cutting

I've been training on and off for the past two years, but only consistently for the past 9 months and currently I'm 185lbs (6'2"). However I wasn't following a specific program and I was only using a pair of adjustable dumbbells and a pull-up bar.

I have now been doing Stronglifts 5x5 for 4 weeks while eating 1800-2200 calories, depending if its a workout day or not. I am also doing intermittent fasting, and cycle my carbs by having low carbs on off-days and high carbs on workout days. I eat 1-1.5g protein per pound of body weight. I normally have a cheat day on the weekend where I have around 4000 calories.

This is how I looked right before I started Stronglifts:
[image]

I know most people would recommend a bulk for me especially on Stronglifts 5x5, but my priority is to rid myself of as much fat as possible while hopefully maintaining muscle or even building a little (since I am new to many of exercises in Stronglifts). I estimate my bodyfat at 15-16% and would like to get down to 10% before I clean bulk.

My current lifts on Stronglifts are:

Squat: 175lb 5x5

Bench: 135lb 5x5

Deadlift: 190lb 1x5

Rows: 105lb 5x5

Overhead press (seated): 85lb 5x5

The only exercise that is giving me difficulty at this point are squats. I have failed to complete 5 reps in the 5th set for the last couple of workouts, but I continued to add weight since I can complete 4 sets no problem. I'm thinking that my difficulty with squats is not strength-related, but more so due to decreased stamina caused by my caloric deficit. Should I only do 3x5 for squats in this case since I am cutting?

Any other feedback or advice cutting while doing Stronglifts? Anybody have any experience with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Doing something like StrongLifts 5x5, Starting Strength, or Madcow on a calorie deficit is like running into a headwind.  It will be harder to make good progress with the weights.  Essentially, you will run out of energy before you feel like you are really challenging your strength.  There's nothing magical about any of the programs I listed, but the lot of them together will help you figure out what's reasonable.

You might plan on a weekly progression (which is still pretty quick) that incorporates all the important things.  NOTE: this is not Mehdi approved, but it's still a decent approach:

**Monday:**

- Bench: 3x5+ (last set as many reps as possible)
- Squat: 3x5+ (last set as many reps as possible)
- Rows: 3x8
- 20 minutes of cardio

**Wednesday:**

- OHP: 3x5+ (last set as many reps as possible)
- Deadlift: 1x5+ (at least 5 reps)
- Pullups/Chinups/Lat Pulldowns: 3xF or 3x10 (alternate pullups and chinups 3xF if you can, or just do lat pulldowns 3x10)
- 20 minutes of cardio

**Friday:**

- Bench: 2x5, 3 at +5 lbs, 8 at 75%
- Squat: 2x5, 3 at +5 lbs, 8 at 75%
- Bro work of your choice 3x8 (curls, shoulder work, etc.)
- 20 minutes of cardio

Basically, use the weights you are working with now to start, on Friday you do one set at 5lbs more than you did on Monday.  The next week, you use that new weight for the squat/bench, and add 5lbs to your OHP and deadlifts.  The arrangement is inspired a bit by all three of the programs in the beginning.  The last lift on all three days is there to keep you healthy, including the bro work.

This approach will be a sustainable pace for much longer than you can do SL5x5 as written--deficit or not.  The advantage of not trying to increase weight every single time you step in the gym is that it ingrains a pattern of patience which will serve you much better over time.  I've watched a number of people who get frustrated that they can't keep up the pace with 5x5 after they've exhausted the program.

Just a little anecdote to keep in mind.  I trained my daughter for her first power lifting competition this past year.  When we started she was able to do about half of what the federation records had for her age/weight class.  She was able to keep the pace of increasing weight every week for over three months of training before we started really preparing for the competition.  At competition, she either beat or tied the federation records with her openers.  Every lift after that was setting a new record altogether.  Even on a deficit you should be able to keep the pace for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth response! Since I'm not really having any difficulty adding weight yet to my lifts (except for my issue with squats) do you think I should continue on Stronglifts until I stall, and then switch to the routine you outlined above? Oh I forgot to add that I added a few supplementary exercises to the Stronglifts program, with pullups, dips and barbell curls on one day and chinups, chest flys, and barbell shrugs on the other.

Comment: Dude...a linear progression *with extra accessory work* while on a cut is a recipe for running straight into a brick wall. Berin is absolutely right that adding weight weekly is a much better idea.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend following the StrongLifts protocol for not completing all prescribed reps for an exercise: if "you didn't accomplish 5x5 on your Squat...you do NOT increase the weight the next workout for that exercise." Page 47. If you fail to get all the reps for that weight 3 times in a row, deload by 10%. Once deloading stops working, then switch to 3x5.

If you're not going to follow the program, the direction to stray is towards adding weight *less* frequently because you're on a cut, not *more* frequently. Repeatedly going to failure by grinding out heavy squats risks poor form and injury.

For that matter, if you're on a cut, you might want to stop increasing the weights *at all* and instead add cardio, either on off days or with a finisher at the end of your workout.

Also, why are you doing seated instead of standing overhead press?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess I just felt like I wasn't really pushing myself too hard, I was just running out of energy towards the end of my sets. My legs have yet to ever get sore from the squats so I figured I could keep increasing the weight. I'll try keeping the weight the same next workout.

As for why I'm doing seated overhead press, I workout in my basement which unfortunately has a low ceiling.

Comment: @user7194 Your legs aren't sore, but what about your back? Squats are not a leg exercise. Plus, soreness is not a good indicator of whether or not an exercise is working--whether you can complete the set is the best indicator.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing stronglifts on a deficit (1760 calories a day). I am 5'7" and weigh 173. I was 172 when I started back on the program. I had to stop going to the gym for financial reason, and from October '14 to Feb '15 I gained 20 lbs. Over this first four weeks I shot up to 178lbs and I am now on a downward trend. My goal is to lean up (just not be a fat-ass anymore) over 10 to 12 weeks. Then I'll increase my caloric intake again. I am currently eating .75 grams of protein per pound of body weight.
Current lifts:
Squat 210
Bench 120
Row 120
Overhead 90
Dead lift 185
+ I am working my chin-ups and dips to 3x10 w/ body weight.

The point is, you are weak. I am weak too. So don't take offense. How many weeks have you been at this? Your squat should be your dominant lift, IMHO. Fall in love with that lift and follow Medhi's program to the letter. There is no way you should be stalling at 175x5x5. Set you aims at doubling your body weight on the squat and dead lift and matching it on the overhead. At least, that is my goal for 5x5. If the program shifts before then, then so be it.

Comment: +1, although I'd argue that your deadlift should *generally* be stronger than your back squat.